# Why is the key space for a substitution cipher Factorial N

Tags: cryptography, key

I'm taking a crypto course, and we're going over substitution ciphers and their Key space. 
per the instructor, the key space is 26! (approx 2^88) for the English alphabet. there is no reference to key length, probably because a subst cipher's length would be a function of the length of the alphabet, just as the number of options would.

per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_space_%28cryptography%29) the keyspace is the set of all possible keys of a certian length, and is calculated in the same way brute force try counts would be options^length or in this case 26^26.

so what am I not getting here?

Comment: My brain sometimes forget the concept of permutation, etc.. sometime I understand, next time I don't .. weird

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your key is a set of digits, options^length is correct. Every digit may occur several times.

If your key is an alphabet, Factorial N is correct. Say, you want to place the A first. You have 26 options. After that, you have only 25 options for the B because A already occupies one. 24 For the C and so on.

26*25*24*...*1 = 26!

Comment: Ahh, so its the removal from the set upon each selection that does it. I also see another part of my misconception. I had been thinking 26! > 26^26, (probably because of the 2^88 reference). that makes much more sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

That's a bit misleading, both your instructor and Wikipedia are correct.
Generally, key of 26 english letters defines a key space sized `26`<sup>`26`</sup>.

For substitution ciphers over english alphabet `26!` is the correct number representing the key space. That's because for substitution cipher the key is defined as a unique replacement of each letter with another one, e.g. `A -> D, B -> M, C -> Y, etc.` 26 letters --> key can be any permutation of 26-letter set --> `26!`. Due to the uniqueness required for substitution, the key space is effectively smaller than the maximal `26`<sup>`26`</sup>, because some (most) of the keys aren't possible - e.g., you can't map both A and B to D.

Comment: This should have been the answer.